# XLS transformation - ignore namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I have such a simple XML for test

```
<test xmlns="urn:entsoe.eu:wgedi:ecan:totalallocationresultsdocument:6:0">
  <Domain v="old"/>
</test>
```

and this XSL transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Domain/@v[.='old']">
        <xsl:attribute name="v" >
            <xsl:value-of select="'New'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to replace "Old" value on Domain element to "New" value. It is perfectly work in case that I will remove xmlns tag in the sample xml. But in case that xmlns is presented, transformation does not work. Is there any configuration parameter to ignore xmlns or any other way how to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Please search for "xslt default namespace" and you will find 1000 answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "xmlns" represents a default namespace declaration, and it not really something you should ignore, but instead you need to change your XSLT to account for that namespace.

As you are using XSLT 2.0, this can be achieved by using `xpath-default-namespace`. This will mean any elements in your xpath expressions which don't have a namespace prefix will be treated as if they were in the specified namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="urn:entsoe.eu:wgedi:ecan:totalallocationresultsdocument:6:0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Domain/@v[.='old']">
        <xsl:attribute name="v" >
            <xsl:value-of select="'New'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If you really don't know what the namespace will be, you can use a wildcard for the namespace prefix in XSLT 2.0.

Try this too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:Domain/@v[.='old']">
        <xsl:attribute name="v" >
            <xsl:value-of select="'New'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but my goal is little bit complicated as I do not know the final count of the xmlns namespaces. My input XML files can have different xmlns and also some XML can have no xmlns. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how you can use a wildcard to match any namespace.